# Pass Different Columns in Pandas DataFrame in a Custom Function in df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe `df`:

```
  x y z
0 1 2 3
1 4 5 6
2 7 8 9
```

I wanna have two new columns that are x * y and x * z:

```
  x y z xy xz
0 1 2 3  2  3
1 4 5 6 20 24
2 7 8 9 56 63
```

So I define a function `func` (just for example) that takes either the string `'y'` or the string `'z'` as an argument to indicate which column I want to multiply with the column x:

```
def func(row, colName):
    return row['x'] * row[colName]
```

And apply the function to the dataframe `df`:

```
df['xz'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Apparently it is wrong here because I didn't specify the `colName`, `'y'` or `'z'`. Question is, `df.apply()` just takes function name, how do I tell it to take the two arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lambda function with specify columns, but also is necessary change `func`:

```
def func(row, colName):
    return row * colName

cols = ['y', 'z']
for c in cols:
    df['x' + c] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x['x'], x[c]), axis=1)
```

If is not possible change `func`:

```
def func(row, colName):
    return row['x'] * row[colName]

cols = ['y', 'z']
for c in cols:
    df['x' + c] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x, c), axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
   x  y  z  xy  xz
0  1  2  3   2   3
1  4  5  6  20  24
2  7  8  9  56  63
```

Comment: This really works! Just one tiny question, is `'x' + c` a column name? Thought just strings can be used as column names.

Comment: @PacmanKX - exactly, it is list comprehension and for each loop return value from `cols` list. So in firt loop `y` and in second `z`

Answer (score 4):

I think `eval` is perfect here

```
df['x*y'],df['x*z']=df.eval('x*y'),df.eval('x*z')
df
Out[14]: 
   x  y  z  x*y  x*z
0  1  2  3    2    3
1  4  5  6   20   24
2  7  8  9   56   63
```

Comment: He, nice one :)

Comment: Cool one! Thanks!

Comment: Nice indeed. Would fit best if this was OP's real use case.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `assign` in a *dict comprehension*.

**Option 1**
Keeping the first column fixed:

```
def func(row, j):
    return row['x'] * row[j]

cols = ['y', 'z']
df.assign(**{'x' + c : df.apply(func, args=c, axis=1) for c in cols})

   x  y  z  xy  xz
0  1  2  3   2   3
1  4  5  6  20  24
2  7  8  9  56  63
```

---

**Option 2**
An alternative with neither of the columns fixed:

```
def func(row, i, j):
    return row[i] * row[j]

pairs = [('x', 'y'), ('x', 'z')]
df.assign(**{''.join(p) : df.apply(func, args=p, axis=1) for p in pairs})

   x  y  z  xy  xz
0  1  2  3   2   3
1  4  5  6  20  24
2  7  8  9  56  63
```

Comment: I'd prefer the first option, but didn't quite understand what `'x' + c` is. The name of the new column?

Comment: @PacmanKX Exactly, naming the column there. It's just simple string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
df['xz'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x['x'], x[colName]), axis=1)
```

and your function would become:

```
def func(x, colName):
    return x * colName
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas 0.22.0` I was able to do the following to get your expected output:

```
df['xy'] = df.apply(func, axis=1, args='y')
df['xz'] = df.apply(func, axis=1, args='z')
```

The docstring for `pd.DataFrame.apply` shows the following:

```
pd.DataFrame.apply(self, func, axis=0, broadcast=False, raw=False, reduce=None, args=(), **kwds)
.
.
.
args : tuple; Positional arguments to pass to function in addition to the array/series
```

so you need to pass any positional arguments to your `func` using the `args` keyword argument in `df.apply()`

Comment: Without changing the original `func`?

Comment: I did not change the original `func` definition.